# Ipython 2.0 notebook, matplotlib, --pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

In the past I have run Ipython with the --pylab option.  The only way I have found to get the notebook to work without getting the message about the ill-effects of --pylab is to open the notebooks and then

```
> %matplotlib
> import matplotlib.pylab as pl
```

and then do

```
pl.plot(x,y)
```

I would like to put the two commands above in my 00-import.py rather than typing them into the beginning of each notebook
Is there a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Write in a terminal

```
ipython locate
```

this command will return a directory. Inside that directory you will find the folder "profile_default/startup/" 
any Python script located in that directory will be read when ipython start. 
If you write a script with the following lines

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

you will get numpy, matplotlib and inline figures.

Anyway, probably it is a good idea to read [this](http://carreau.github.io/posts/10-No-PyLab-Thanks.ipynb.html).